# invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'HardWare'

Tags: c++

When I was doing my C++ homework yesterday, I tried using pure virtual functions in the basic class and completing them in derived class.
But there's something wrong. I googled it and I found I can't solve it. Google said that I need complete them in the derived class. And yes, I did. But still not work.
Here's Code.

```
//This is a cpp code
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
class HardWare {
public:
    virtual void Work()=0;

protected:
    double num;string name2;
    string name;
};

class CPU: public HardWare{
public: CPU(string a,double b) {
        name=a;num=b;
    }
    void Work() override{
        cout<<name<<" CPU Work with "<<num<<"GHz"<<endl;
    }
};

class MainBoard: public HardWare{
public:
    MainBoard(string a,string b){
        name=a;name2=b;
    }
    void Work() override{
        cout<<name<<" MainBoard Work with "<<name2<<endl;
    }
};

class HardDisk: public HardWare{
public:
    HardDisk(string a,double b) {
        name=a;num=b;
    }
    void Work() override{
        cout<<name<<" HardDisk Work with "<<num<<"G"<<endl;
    }
};

class PC{
protected:
    vector<HardWare> a;
public:
    void AddToPC(HardWare *p){
        a.push_back(*p);
    }
    void Work(){
        for (vector<HardWare>::iterator it=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++)
            it->Work();
        cout<<"PC Work";
    }
};



//StudybarCommentBegin
int main()
{
    PC *p = new PC(); 
    HardWare *p1 = new CPU("Intel",4.5); 
    HardWare *p2 = new CPU("AMD",3.8); 
    HardWare *p3 = new MainBoard("ASUS","ATX");
    HardWare *p4 = new HardDisk("Seagate",500);
    HardWare *p5 = new HardDisk("Sumsang",1000);

    p->AddToPC(p1);
    p->AddToPC(p2);
    p->AddToPC(p3);
    p->AddToPC(p4);
    p->AddToPC(p5);

    p->Work();  //output all of the parts of the PC

}

//StudybarCommentEnd
```

Comment: You need to use a `vector<HardWare*>` in you `PC` class. What you are doing right now is copying derived classes to base class objects. Which is object slicing for one, and also not allowed since the base class has pure virtual methods.

Comment: In addition your code has a memory leak.